# JavaScript: validation for the sum of rows and sum of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I developed a form and I want to allow submitting it if and only if:

1- Total of rows is greater than zero and less than or equal to 100 meaning between (1-100)

2- Total of columns is equal to 100 not more not less.

So I come up with the following page:

***View:***

[image]

***Code:***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var isvalid=true;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#test").prop("disabled",true);
    $(".tabbody input[type=number]").blur(function(){
        validateSubmit();
    });
});
function validateSubmit()
{
    var retval = sumRowVals();
    $("#btn-save").prop("disabled",!retval);
    $("#msgdiv").html(retval ? "":"Invalid inputs!!!");
}
function sumRowVals()
{
    isvalid=true;
    resetFigs();
    var rindx=1;
    $(".tabbody tr").not(':first').each(function(){
        var temp=0;
        var cindx=1;
        $("input[type=number]",this).each(function(){
            var elval = !isNaN($(this).val()) ? parseInt($(this).val()):0;
            var sumcol = $("#ccol"+cindx);
            $(sumcol).html(parseInt($(sumcol).html())+elval);
            temp=temp+elval;
            cindx++;
            if(elval > 100){isvalid=false;}
            if(!(parseInt($(sumcol).html()) > 0 && parseInt($(sumcol).html()) <= 100)){isvalid=false;}
        });
        if(rindx != $('.tabbody tr').not(':first').length)
        {
            if(temp != 100){isvalid=false;}
            $("#rcol"+rindx).html(temp);
        }
        rindx++;
    });
    return isvalid;
}
function resetFigs()
{
    $('*[id*=ccol]').each(function() {
    $(this).html("0");
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
  <table class="tabbody">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>plo1</td>
      <td>plo2</td>
      <td>plo3</td>
      <td>total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> slo1 </td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col1" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col2" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col3" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td id="rcol1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> slo2 </td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col1" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col2" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col3" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td id="rcol2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> slo3 </td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col1" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col2" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col3" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td id="rcol3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> slo4 </td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col1" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col2" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="col3" min="0" max="100"></td>
      <td id="rcol4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> total </td>
      <td id="ccol1"></td>
      <td id="ccol2"></td>
      <td id="ccol3"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="msgdiv" style="color:red;line-height:30px"></div>
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE" id="btn-save"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the view the data is correct but the error shows invalid inputs:

[DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/nq0nLffs/)

***How to fix this with minimum changes?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try and understand what you've wrote! coz you are not checking conditions that you've mentioned above.

Second, KISS - Keep It Simple Stupid! Why make something look so complex? coz why do you need to call it on every blur, and if you must why name fn validateSumbit().?

Thrid, Always give Proper names to variables. coz, give proper names so you can easily see what you're doing and correct yourself(like you were checking condition of column on rowSum).

Finally, below is your working JS,

```
var isvalid=true;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#test").prop("disabled",true);
    $(".tabbody input[type=number]").blur(function(){
        validateSubmit();
    });
});
function validateSubmit()
{
    var retval = sumRowVals();
    $("#btn-save").prop("disabled",!retval);
    $("#msgdiv").html(retval ? "":"Invalid inputs!!!");
}
function sumRowVals()
{
    isvalid=true;
    resetFigs();
    var elval = 0;
    var rindx=1;
    $(".tabbody tr").not(':first').each(function(){
        var rowSum=0;
        var cindx=1;
        $("input[type=number]",this).each(function(){
            elval = 0;
            elval = ($(this).val()=="") ? 0:parseInt($(this).val());
            var sumcol = $("#ccol"+cindx);
            $(sumcol).html(parseInt($(sumcol).html())+elval);
            rowSum=rowSum+elval;
            cindx++;
            if(elval > 100){isvalid=false;}
            //if(!(parseInt($(sumcol).html()) > 0 && parseInt($(sumcol).html()) <= 100)){isvalid=false;}
        });
        if(rindx != $('.tabbody tr').not(':first').length)
        {
            if(!(rowSum  > 0 &&  rowSum <= 100)){isvalid=false;}
            $("#rcol"+rindx).html(rowSum);
        }
        rindx++;
    });
    $('*[id*=ccol]').each(function() {
    var tmp = parseInt($(this).html());
        if(tmp != 100)
        {
            isvalid=false;
        }
    });
    return isvalid;
}
function resetFigs()
{
    $('*[id*=ccol]').each(function() {
    $(this).html("0");
});
}
```

JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rhu5snev/) is here.

hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for every single word, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Happy to help :)